# Elm - How to use HTML events?

Tags: elm

The Elm [getting started guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/) doesn't seem to use the standard Elm HTML events and I'm not sure how to use them. For example, [`onBlur`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.1/Html-Events#onBlur):

```
view model =
  div []
    [ div []
      input [ type_ "text", onInput MsgA ] []
    , input [ type_ "text", onBlur MsgB ] []
    ]
```

This fails in the compiler because now I am returning type `Html (String -> Msg)` on line 3 but `Html (Msg)` in line two.

Why are these two events incompatible? Is there any way to use both at the same time? Additionally, the docs don't make it clear enough for someone like me to understand how to use `onBlur`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onBlur` has a different type signature than `onInput`.

```elm
onInput : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg

onBlur : msg -> Attribute msg
```

That means whatever `Msg` you use for `onInput` has to take a single string parameter. Likewise, the `Msg` used in `onBlur` cannot take a parameter. If you redefined `MsgA` and `MsgB` to the following, it would compile:

```elm
type Msg
    = MsgA String
    | MsgB
```

**Edit**

If you wanted your blur handler to be able to accept the target value, you can roll your own like this:

```elm
import Html.Events exposing (on, targetValue)
import Json.Decode as Json

onBlurWithTargetValue : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onBlurWithTargetValue tagger =
    on "blur" (Json.map tagger targetValue)
```

Comment: Thanks @ChadGilbert. That's a little clearer. I'm still thinking I need `onBlur` to take a parameter so that I can get the value of that input in the `MsgB` branch of `update`. Could you give an example of the usage of `onBlur` alongside usage of `onInput`?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example where the "blur" event can give you the current value.

Comment: Whoa. Elm continues to show me I don't understand it at all. Thanks a ton.